# Is it possible to edit a bookmark in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I did a quick search and couldn't find anything on this being explicitly stated.  I have added a native Eclipse bookmark to first mark a section I want to pay attention to, and later wanted to back to it in the hopes of editing the comment, saying I had investigated that block of code when I specifically ran the program down the code path.

So my question that I'm trying to find an explicit yes or no for is, is there a *native* way in Eclipse to edit a bookmark without having to delete and add it again, without having to install from probably several custom plugins, or is there another feature I can use for my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually yes, you can edit a bookmark description. Go to `Windows` -> `Show View` and chose `Bookmarks`. That will open a bookmark view where you can view your bookmarks and edit them.

Comment: I have opened this view and found some help documents.  I still don't believe you are able to edit them, even in this panel.

Sources:
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-28.htm
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-37-3c.htm

Comment: Ah, I see that I am actually able to edit an existing bookmark by **single-clicking** on the bookmark row under the description column, or I can right-click the bookmark row, selecting _Properties_ in the context menu, and change it in the dialog that comes up as well.  Thanks

Comment: @Pysis: I'm glad I was able to help. If this answer helped you accept/upvote it.